# MS Chart how to find a datapoint using an X-value? C#

Tags: c#, .net, mschart

Does anybody know how to interpolate in MS Chart?

By that I mean how to find a datapoint in a series using an X-value? Hopefully being able to search for the closest datapoint corresponding to that X-value. I'd prefer not to iterate through the series.

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly add (x,y) values to the point ToolTip,

```
chart.Series[chart.Series.Count - 1].Points
.Select((d, i) => (d, i))
.Where(p => p.d.ToolTip.Contains(x.ToString()) && p.d.YValues[0] == y)
.FirstOrDefault();
```